# Why email field {!Account.Name} is not populating whenever the email is sent out?

Tags: apex, email-alert, merge-field, alert

I have a simple classic email template of type text.

In the email template I use merge field value `{!Account.Name}`.

When the alert is send via workflow rule the `{!Account.Name}` is visible in sent out email.

When the alert is send via apex trigger the `{!Account.Name}` is not visible in sent out email.

Here is my code:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> lstMsgs = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
// Create a dummy Contact
Contact tempContact = new Contact(email = 'recipient@email.com', firstName = 'recipientFirstName', lastName = 'recipientLastName');
insert tempContact;
msg.setSaveAsActivity(false);
msg.setWhatId(accountId);
msg.setTemplateId(templateId);
msg.setTargetObjectId(tempContact.Id);
lstMsgs.add(msg);
Messaging.sendEmail(lstMsgs);
delete tempContact;
```

Why email field {!Account.Name} is not populating whenever the email is sent out via apex trigger?

Comment: It depends on what parameters you provide the method. You should include any relevant code.

Comment: @sfdcfox I've included my apex code which is generating and sending the email alert. Still merge field value is not populating whenever the email is sent out. Please advise.

Comment: Your Contact was not inserted pointing at a parent Account

Comment: @cropredy If I understood it correctly I need to connect the Contact with the Account. I did it the following way: Contact tempContact = new Contact(email = 'recipient@email.com', firstName = 'recipientFirstName', lastName = 'recipientLastName', `accountId = merchantId`);  

Still merge field value is not populating whenever the email is sent out.

Comment: given that, then do this `msg.setWhatId(tempContact.AccountId);` instead of what you have. Also -- try commenting out the delete of tempContact as the email will reference something that doesn't exist

Comment: @cropredy I did what you advised but get the followin: `FATAL_ERROR System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_TYPE_FOR_OPERATION, Only User, Contact, Lead, or Person objects are allowed for targetObjectId:` Any other ideas?

Comment: Use [edit] and amend your post to the current code state

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set a WhatId on ApexMessage if you're setting TargetObjectId(). Try removing setWhatId().